# Isn't the key redundant in the following code?

Tags: c#

I started learning about MVC 6 and I found [this](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html#use-fiddler-to-call-the-api) tutorial.

The following code is quoted from the linked site:

```
//TodoItem.cs
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The TodoItem class will be a value field in a ConcurrentDictionary:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, TodoItem> _todos =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TodoItem>();
```

The key field which has string type will contain the same value as TodoItem.Key:

```
public void Add(TodoItem item)
{
    item.Key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _todos[item.Key] = item;
}
```

Does this means that each time a new item is added the the Key will stored twice(once is the key field of the dictionary and once inside the value field) or I am missing something?

I came across this situation in C++ using std::map too and I always used something like this to avoid storing the value of Key two times:

```
struct Item
{
    //std::string Key;
    std::string Name;
    bool IsComplete;
};

std::map<std::string, Item> items;
//       ^^ Item.Key
```

Comment: `std::map<std::string, Item> items;` in c++ is a different model. You may rather want to compare with `std::unordered_map<std::string, Item> items;` in c++.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this means that each time a new item is added the the Key will
>   stored twice(once is the key field of the dictionary and once inside
>   the value field) or I am missing something?

In .NET System.String type is a reference type, so you shouldn't be worried about the key being stored twice. It will be a single instance in memory to which both the Key of the dictionary and the Key property of the item are simply pointing to. So don't worry about redundancy in this situation. The `ConcurrentDictionary` structure that you are using here is just a simple wrapper of pointers around your actual data.

Also worth mentioning another interesting property of the System.String type in .NET. Even if you have 2 different instances of a string with the same value the runtime could decide to *intern* them and they will point to the same data in memory:

```
string a = "abc";
string b = "abc";
bool res = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b); // true
```

Comment: Yes good point about string interning being optional. I have updated my answer to include this important remark.

Comment: You must mean `bool res = (object)a == (object)b;` or similar. Otherwise you will not test if they are the same instance or not (reference equality). In C#, `==` has a special built-in overload for strings which checks if the _values_ are the same (an ordinal comparison, coordinatewise as UTF-16 code units).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, yes you are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out.